# Jacoco java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting Class

Tags: android, android-testing, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I recently moved to another computer and needed to reset all my environment.

So, this tests was working before.

But I didnt remember which version of Java/JDK I was using before.

Well, the problem is:

```
java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting path/to/class
```

I'm using **Jacoco "0.8.1"**

```
java --version
openjdk 17.0.1 2021-10-19
```

and JDK 1.8

Can anyone know how to handle with it?

Answer (score 25):

Strange to see statement

> and JDK 1.8

together with

> ```
> java --version
> openjdk 17.0.1 2021-10-19
> ```

from the last one seems that actually you're using **JDK 17**

> I'm using Jacoco "0.8.1"

We (developers of JaCoCo) advice to always use latest released version as new versions come with fixes and improvements (IMO updating versions of your dependencies and tools - is a very good practice also in general), so please try this - as of today latest released JaCoCo version is **0.8.7**, and exactly in this version JDK 17 support was added.

Comment: maybe OP meant the project itself is java 8?

Comment: changing from 0.8.5 to 0.8.7 removed all those errors for me

Comment: Have the same issue, also unit test that fails. Using Jacoco 0.8.8 with JDK 18 (language level JDK 17).

Comment: @RoyWasse do you solve the issue ? Same issue here..

Comment: Tried 0.8.7 and 0.8.8 neither of them resolve the issue

Answer (score 12):

Java 17 need jacoco 0.8.8 and above. reload pom.xml and it works

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.8</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

While I was Testing my build in cmd using the command mvnw test, i got "Build Erorr"  java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting sun/util/resources/cldr/provider/CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo.

Step to perform:

1.Where to analyse the error.
Always check for build error or any test report  under project folder /target/surefire-reports.
As this a build erorr checkin the dump file
Check for error message . In this particular scenario the error message is
"Jacocojava.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting sun/util/resources/cldr/provider/CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo"

2.Investigate what is causing this error. The java version i had is 17 and Jacoco version i had is 0.8.5. So check your java verison and Jacoco verison

3.Checking java version  Cmd enter java - version : it will display the version
example C:\Automation\projectJenkins\jgsu-spring-petclinic>java -version
java version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17 LTS

4.For java 15 and above  the jococ version compatable is 0.8.7.
Open the pom file of your project and update jococ version. check under Generic properties . Update you version as 0.8.7

example:

```
<jacoco.version>0.8.7</jacoco.version>
```

save the file

5. last step. test your build.
   cmd run MVNW test .
   The issue was reolved and succesfull build was built.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can happen when you have a [multi-module](https://developer.android.com/topic/modularization) Android project, and you're using [Robolectric](https://robolectric.org/) in your app unit tests, and you try to get code coverage data with [Jacoco](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/), using:

- Android Studio ➔ View ➔ Tool Windows ➔ Project pane (of project files) ➔ Select the `"test"` folder ➔ Right-click it ➔ **Run Tests in 'com.company.app' with Coverage**

Android Studio will setup the unit tests (with code coverage) to run like this:

```
:app:testDebugUnitTest --tests "com.company.app.*"
```

So you may experience errors when the tests run. All of the non-Robolectric tests will run and pass, but the tests that are annotated with either `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)` or `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)` will not run, and instead show errors like this:

```
java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting path/to/class with JaCoCo 0.8.8.202204050719/5dcf34a.
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_b6258fc.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:94)
    at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.maybeInstrumentClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:162)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.lambda$loadClass$0(SandboxClassLoader.java:136)
    at org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:53)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.loadClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:136)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getSortedDeclaredFields(TestClass.java:77)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:111)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:91)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:74)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$HelperTestRunner.<init>(SandboxTestRunner.java:353)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner.<init>(RobolectricTestRunner.java:569)

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot process instrumented class com/company/app/MyClass. Please supply original non-instrumented classes.
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_b6258fc.core.internal.instr.InstrSupport.assertNotInstrumented(InstrSupport.java:238)

Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    android/content/res/ResourcesImpl.$$robo$$android_content_res_ResourcesImpl$loadComplexColorForCookie(Landroid/content/res/Resources;Landroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/content/res/ComplexColor; @828: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/Object' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'android/content/res/ComplexColor' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @828
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'android/content/res/ResourcesImpl', 'android/content/res/Resources', 'android/util/TypedValue', integer, 'android/content/res/Resources$Theme', '[I', '[Z', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/Object', 'android/content/res/XmlResourceParser', 'android/util/AttributeSet', integer, 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/Object' }
```

In this case, you need to explicitly add the Java package of your app into the 'Run Configuration' of the unit tests, like this:

- Android Studio ➔ Run ➔ Edit Configurations... ➔ Select the Gradle configuration for `:app:testDebugUnitTest`
- At the right of the dialog, click on 'Modify options ▾' ➔ then click on '**Specify classes and packages**' in the Code Coverage section.

[image: Android Studio - Edit Run Configuration for Unit Tests - Modify Options]

- A blank space should now appear at the bottom of the dialog, with the title "Packages and classes to include in coverage data".
- Click on the "+" symbol ➔ Add Package ➔ Select the main Java package of your app. It should display an entry like `'com.company.app.*'`. Press OK.

[image: Android Studio - Edit Run Configuration for Unit Tests - Add Packages and Classes]

- Then re-run all your unit tests. They should work now.